# SharePoint links to View/Edit/New PowerApps full page forms?

Tags: sharepoint-online

The following links will take you to full page versions of PowerApps forms for New and Edit in modern SharePoint:

https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/Lists/mylist/NewForm.aspx?ID=1
https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/Lists/mylist/EditForm.aspx?ID=1

You can also access the details view, but it goes to classic mode (no PowerApp form):

https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/Lists/mylist/DispForm.aspx?ID=1

Am I referencing the wrong aspx page or is it simply not available?

Settings for SharePointIntegration:

OnNew:
Set(SharePointFormMode, "CreateForm"); NewForm(FormNew1); Navigate(ScreenNew, ScreenTransition.None)

OnEdit:
Set(SharePointFormMode, "EditForm"); EditForm(FormEdit1); Navigate(ScreenEdit, ScreenTransition.None)

OnView:
Set(SharePointFormMode, "ShowForm"); ViewForm(FormView1); Navigate(ScreenView, ScreenTransition.None)

If I remove the Navigate from all the above, clicking Edit or New will take me to my Display View in all its glory. This proves the Display View of the form does work, but is not a long term solution because the new and edit buttons should really go to their respective screens.

Cleared my caches and tried in IT, Chrome, and Firefox. Really not sure what is tripping it up to send me to the classic version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to add &pa=1 to the end:

https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/Lists/mylist/DispForm.aspx?ID=1&pa=1